# Standard out is showing up in standard error in jenkins and eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jenkins, stderr

I've just started on a new project where log statements that you would expect to show in standard out are appearing in std error. For example in eclipse INFO statements are showing up as red and in jenkins they show up in the Std Error category:

```
Standard Error

May 17, 2015 8:00:49 PM com.s3.hddmanager.eventstable.OptimizeOnline removeForeignKey
INFO: Removing old foreign key 'HistoryBool_ibfk_1' from table 'HistoryBool'
```

We don't have any idea on what could be miss configured but would like this to be properly configured in our project. So very annoying. Any advice is greatly appreciated. We are using an ant build.

Comment: I think you need to provide a lot more information, such as why you expect the log statements to show up on stdout.  The default configuration of the logging frameworks I have experience from is to log on stderr.

Comment: Are you alive? How did you solve it?

Comment: @Čamo I think my logging system was just logging to standard error. We just learned to live with it.

Comment: I am sorry for that :)